# Redirect all ports to OpenVPN client

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I want to redirect all ports from VPN server to one of VPN client (except the SSH-5656 port and OpenVPN port-5757).

I know this command:

```
iptables -A FORWARD --proto tcp -p 1-5655 -j DSTNAT -d 10.8.0.x
```

But I don´t know, how to redirect more ports with one command.

For example: I want to redirect ports from 1-5655 to client 10.8.0.2 (TCP + UDP) and then I want to redirect 5657-5756 & 5758-65535 (both protocols) to the same OpenVPN client.

Can you please help me with that?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There is the parameter multiport

```
-m multiport --dports 1:5655,5758:65535 -j DSTNAT
```

**Edit:** with "-m multiport" specifies a match to use. In our case the module "multiport", after that is necessary to specify the destination (--dport) or source (--sport) port range with the syntax "from_port:to_port". You can add additional port range by separating it with a comma, for ex. (1:5655,5758:65535).

**Note:** "multiport" can only be used by specifying the protocol with -p tcp or -p udp

Comment: Can you please extend your answer, add some explanations...

Comment: @RomeoNinov I have added an explaination! I hope it's more clear :)